# Is this a possible attack? Can I avoid it?

Tags: iis, server-side-attacks

today I arrived and I have 200 (automatic) errors in my logs from my applicaction.
I'm not sure if it was an attack, or something weird in my IIS or my application.
The error was alwasys the same, as someone tried to go to a inexistent page.

The error was: **Void CheckVirtualFileExists(System.Web.VirtualPath)**

For example, I have my Login.aspx, and I have 19 errros that someone tried to enter in this 19 pages that doesn't exist:

- Login_backup.aspx
- Login_old.aspx
- Login_bak.aspx
- backup_Login.aspx
- bak_Login.aspx
- old_Login.aspx
- __Login.aspx
- .....similar ones

Was this an attack or it was something bad configured? 
Is there a way to avoid it?

I really want to know if it was something we could change so this will not happen again.

Comment: Someone was probably probing your site for old login files that could be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Lasse V.Karlsen you were right.

Hopefully(?) it was an audit someone in the IT department was doing, but nobody reported me until now.